# Include a job in the database backup, to be activated when the backup is restored

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs, database-backups, job-scheduling

When I take a backup of a database (SQL Server), is there any way that I can include a scheduled job in the backup?

I have a database with stored procedures and a maintenance job that runs some of the stored procedures nightly.

I would like to achieve a minimal effort to schedule the job, when the .bak file is restored into a server, back as a database.

Comment: Not clear.  First paragraph backup and last paragraph is restore.

Comment: Yes, correct. Objective: Restoring a .bak and get the job running. Possible means: Including it in the backup? Can it be done? Clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the quick button to click for your problem, but I think (not sitting in front of it right now) You can right click a job and get a script for its creation including scheduling specifics. I don't know how to include a job in a backup and how to restore it, though. I think restoring a job would require a script with the CREATE for the job to be run.

Comment: You are right, the context menu holds `Script Job as > CREATE To >` editor or file. I could include this in the .bak as an SP. And then the user restoring the .bak would have to get instructions to execute it.

Comment: all in one would be nice: write a script that executes the restore and then executes the CREATE of the job. User would only need to run one script. How about the tips here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a8ef9b90-bb08-4e82-b6cb-e19cc890edbb/how-to-execute-any-tsql-script-after-database-restore?forum=sqlexpress

Answer (score 1):

You can also back up the msdb database. The msdb database is where all the jobs live, it is one of the system databases, and then restore your database plus msdb.